# How to implement a 3D dataFrame structure?

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, 3d

I am trying to represent some 3D data using pandas and kind of have no idea about it. I know it can be done with numpy and thought it should not be hard to use pandas as it is easier for indexing. So here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

date=[2015, 2016, 2017]
interval=np.arange(-10,11)
elevation=np.arange(0.0,3.25,0.25)
df=pd.DataFrame(index=interval, columns=elevation)
```

The result of df is shown below. Notice I have a list of years in the variable date above. I want to represent the below for each year stored in a dataFrame objective. How to go about doing this?

[image: output of df from above]

Comment: Was experimenting with dictionaries and created a dictionary of DataFrames but not sure if that is the best way to handle this. So one could do the following: dic={'2015':df, '2016':df, '2017':df}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiindex should do the trick for you. However, since your trying with dictionaries, you could also do the following and get a multiindex dataframe:

```
date=[2015, 2016, 2017]
interval=np.arange(-10,11)
elevation=np.arange(0.0,3.25,0.25)
df=pd.DataFrame(index=interval, columns=elevation)
dic = {x:df for x in date}
df = pd.concat(dic.values(), keys= dic.keys())
```

So if you want to see a specific year, for example 2016, you just do:

```
df.loc[2016]
```

Comment: Ok..so how would I index into the date? with the dataFrame defined as you did?

Comment: the line dic = {x:df for x in date} is creating a dataframe with index (year, interval). So you're going to create a 2D dataframe with a multidimensional key (year, interval). Therefore,  if you slice using the 2 dimension on your index, it is in a way the same as navigating through a cube of data. Just run my code as is and you'll see :)

Comment: are you satisfied with the answer?

Comment: I ran your code and printed the output which looks good. However, I still dont get an idea on how to extract the 2D data for a specific year. For example, print df gives the full dataframe, df[0.00] gives all the data for all three years at 0.00. What if I wanted to display or even plot only year 2016?